# window.location.href.replace replace/remove part of the url when it is multiple cases to replace

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how to replace/remove part of the url when it is multiple cases to replace. I tried adding each per line but it only makes the last one work so I assume I need to bundle them somehow?

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

```
  function showFullPage(obj) {
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("?header=false", "");
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("management?header=false", "");
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("files?header=false", "");
// window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("events?header=false", "");
// window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("broadcasts?header=false", "");
// window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("network?header=false", "");
// window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("chat?header=false", "");
```

}

Comment: Setting `window.location.href` immediately redrects to a new page. Create an [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), test `pathname` with [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and if the test succeed, `delete` a query parameter in `URLSearchParams` object. Then assign the modified URL to `location.href`.

Comment: thanks so much for the quick reply. And sorry to be a. newbie but i only get part of that. Can I trouble you for an example:
one extension to be removed is this: ?header=false
Another extension is: /management?header=false
Another is: /files?header=false
Always from the end...
Much appreciated in advance
Cam

Comment: @Teemu it's ok... i worked out a hack. I simply placed the ?header=false last in the string.... after you mentioned how it works I realised I could try this :) Cheers

Comment: Is the last folder name important? I mean if the last name in the path is ex. "admin", should that and `header` parameter be removed?